# How to generate one object using multiple objects in ARCore?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Does anyone know how to generate single object using multiple objects in ARCore?

for example, generate a table using table parts like legs etc.

In fact, i have no idea whether it's possible or not.

is it possible to do this in runtime?

Comment: Hi @HCJEONG, what do you mean exactly saying "...using multiple objects in ARCore" ?

Comment: Also see the [ARCore samples page](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/samples) for ideas but otherwise your question needs more detail as to what problems you are encountering.

Comment: @Andy srry. for example, making a single model with multiple other models (like assembling a furniture)

Comment: Assembling like in these videos?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQKzoaj2cHQ 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUCGsLRC92o

Comment: @Andy yeah, similar to it. but i didn't mean the animation things. if user adjust the height of the table legs. the table gets taller (i know if i use just single table model, there's a way to do it. but i want to use separated parts. for example. if user adjust the height of the table legs. the table legs get taller not the whole table model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Assembling`/`transforming` animation of 3D models doesn't depend on ARCore at all. All you need is to prepare an animation of transformed parts of your 3D scene (you can do it in 3D authoring tool like 3dsMax, Maya, Modo, Cinema4D, Blender, etc), then you need to combine all those 3D components into a single group that has just a single **pivot point**. Then save your 3D scene in any supported format: `.obj`, `.gltf` or `.fbx`.

[image]

If you've built an ARCore app with plane detection, image detection or face detection feature – at runtime (after a two-second tracking) you automatically get `ARAnchor` which must meet a `pivot point` of a group where all the animated components reside. That's it.